# Port forwarding ports to two hosts

Tags: port-forwarding

Is it possible to port forward the exact same ports to two different machines?

These machines will never both be up at the same time. I tried doing this with iptables on Ubuntu 14.04. Port forwarding itself works fine, but not when I add two different IP addresses for the same ports. Even either of the hosts is offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not fw one `port` to two `ip addr`. Only you can do is to set different `port` on `host` or make different `in` port.

Something like

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.200:8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.201:8080
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.201 --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Replase `ports`, `interface` and `ip` with you network parameters

Comment: I am using the top line indeed for port forwarding. Thanks the explanation, I will modify the incoming port, the output was the most important one. Thanks!